# How does Facebook scrape my website and how can I manually change this information?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, web-scraping

I am using the iFrame version of the Facebook like button and was wondering how Facebook scrapes my website. They pulled information in the middle of the page, which was the first paragraph tag, instead of taking from the divs earlier. I was wondering if this is normal and how often Facebook updates their page.

Secondly, I am having problems editing this information in the page settings on the Facebook page that was generated. It would be nice if I could manually override whatever Facebook scrapes from my website.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ogp.me/ — more specifically, using an Open Graph description.